# How to reopen the same form created with a class

Tags: java, scope, switch-statement

Class Tracker is set to Hide_on_Close, which is what creates my form.
I have a switch that I am trying to first open the form if its never been opened, then redisplay the SAME form with all the data on it when the switch is envoked the second time.

I am just learning to code and I don't know how to reopen the same form. I can open a new instance of it just fine but all the data is gone.

```
    `public class Zoner extends JFrame {

  public JTextPane pane;

  public JMenuBar menuBar;

  public JToolBar toolBar;   
  Tracker tracker1 = null;

`Globals.comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch (i){
              case 0 : 
                  if(tracker1 == null) {
            tracker1 = new Tracker();
        } else {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Same form");         
            tracker1.setVisible(true);
        }



              break;

The code for Class Tracker is as follows... Removed all the swing ui stuff..

    class Tracker {
    private Integer wHitCounter = 0 ;
    private Integer COCCounter = 0 ;
    private JFrame frame1;
    public Tracker()
    {
// Create form
     Object choice =(Globals.comboBox )
                      .getSelectedItem();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Zoner: " + choice);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setSize(1024,850);
     Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
     //Set up Gui form

    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    contentPane.setLayout(layout);
pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void setVisible(boolean bool) {
        frame1.setVisible(bool);
    }
}
```

Updated crashes on line frame1.setVisible(bool);
with code Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What is `Tracker`? Is it a `JFrame`?

Comment: its a class that is a JFrame with swing UI Components on it

Comment: dont capitalize the first letter in variable names, that is reserved for Class declarations. It makes your code confusing and hard to read

Comment: thanks redFIVE. I will have to get that cleaned up.

Comment: J Woodchuck   RunTracker was how  I was determining if the form had been created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should know that you have 2 `JFrame` objects:

1. Tracker is a `JFrame` itself. When you create an instance of `Tracker`, you are also creating a new `JFrame`
2. `Tracker` creates a `JFrame` within it's constructor.

That means when you create a `Tracker` object, you are creating 2 `JFrame` objects (the `Tracker` object that is a `JFrame`, as well as the `JFrame` within the `Tracker`).

Start off by removing `extends JFrame`, and specifying your frame in the field:

```
class Tracker {
    private JFrame frame;

    public Tracker() {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can now expose a method, `setVisible`, allowing you to show/hide your frame at will:

```
class Tracker {
    private JFrame frame;

    public Tracker() {
        //...
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean bool) {
        frame.setVisible(bool);
    }
}
```

That fixes up your `Tracker` class. Now for the switch statement.

Instead of the `int RunTracker1`, you could use a boolean. Instead of `RunTracker1 = 1`, you could do `RunTracker1 = true`. You should also make the first letter of that variable lowercase:

```
if(!runTracker1) {
    //...
    runTracker1 = true;
}
```

But that variable isn't needed at all. Instead, put the `Tracker tracker1` variable before the switch, possibly in the field of the class you are in:

```
Tracker tracker1 = null;
switch(i) {
    case 0:

        break;
}
```

Then you could check to see if `tracker1` is `null` to determine whether the form has been created:

```
Tracker tracker1 = null;
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        if(tracker1 == null) {
            tracker1 = new Tracker();
        } else {
            //display
        }
        break;
}
```

Notice how I changed `Tracker1` to `tracker1`, to avoid ambiguity between variables and types. Variables should start with a lowercase letter, types (classes/interfaces/enums) start with uppercase letters.

Now that you are preserving the `Tracker` (possibly in the field), you can call methods on it if it has already been created:

```
Tracker tracker1 = null;
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        if(tracker1 == null) {
            tracker1 = new Tracker();
        } else {
            tracker1.setVisible(true);
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: I guess that is actually what I do not know how to do.//call method to display tracker1

Comment: Throws Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at tracker1.setVisible(true);

Comment: @JeremiahStillings You must be doing something wrong. This code makes sure `tracker1` is ***not*** null before attempting to use it. I'm guessing you created 2 `tracker1` variables, one which is shadowing the other. Please add the updated the code into your question to reflect what you currently have.

Comment: Code Updated. Thank you for all the time your putting into this

Comment: Its passing the null check its on the second time thru the switch that i am crashing.

Comment: @JeremiahStillings That's because you do `JFrame frame = new JFrame()` instead of `frame1 = new JFrame()`. You initialize a totally different frame, as well as never initialize `frame1`, which is why `setVisible` throws `NullPointerException` (`frame1` is `null`). Replace `JFrame frame = new JFrame()` with `frame1 = new JFrame()`.

Comment: @JeremiahStillings No problem. Don't forget to upvote this answer and mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark under the vote buttons! :)